# Vue.js + TypeScript importing plain js function

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am trying to import external JS function from separate file into my Vue.js app which is running on TypeScript.

products_table.js

```
function init_products_table() {
    console.log('test')
}

export {init_products_table as initProductsTable}
```

And I import it into my Vue component like this:

```
import { initProductsTable } from '../../products_table.js'
```

And I get this compile error:

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '../../products_table.js'.

Comment: Did you set allowJs to be true in your tsconfig file?

Comment: It helped! Although the IDE still shows TS7016 error on import part. But compiler works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you use TS with Vue.JS you should enable JS in your 'tsconfig.json' file.
After some recommendation:

- importing a JS file into TS is a bit counterproductive, I advise you to code your external function in TS directly, this can avoid future conflicts.
- when importing you don't have to give the file type. Here '../../products_table.js' would be '../../products_table'.

If the problem persists please let me know.